# How to display a floating point result of a division of two integers?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with displaying and keeping any floating number or double or long or floating type this is the code :

```
int sd, n;
float d;    
d=n/sd.capacity();

cout << d.toFloat() << endl;
cout << n << " / " << sd.capacity() << " = " << d << endl;
```

In the output I have d equal to 0 everytime, sd.capacity() and n are never 0, so all the time n is lower than sd.capacity value, d = 0 but it should never 0. The variable d does not contain anything but 0.

Comment: `float` is a primitive, not an object. It has no `toFloat()` member function, or any other member functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int`/`int` results into `int`. So this does a problem.

You need to have atleast one of the operands as `float`.

Since, you are telling that `n` always `<` than `sd.capacity()`, so `n/sd.capacity()` in `int` division always gives 0.

I suppose you should do,

```
d= (float)n / (float)sd.capacity();
```

Does this solve it?

Comment: yeah  done thank's a lot 

solved by this thank's

   

     d= (float)n / (float)sd.capacity();

Comment: Glad to help :). But from next time try to search about your question, or else repeated questions often get downvoted badly.

Comment: You don't need to cast both `n` and `sd.capacity()` to `float`. The division will be floating point if at least one of them is a `float`.

Comment: I have already mentioned it...